# Different Document library default views on specific pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, view

I have different pages on my SharePoint site that I would like to display the Documents library. However, I would like a different default view on each of the pages. So when each page is navigated to, there is a documents web part displaying a unique view. I am working in SharePoint online, and would prefer to avoid using SharePoint Designer if possible.

Comment: Hi @John, welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge :) Thank you for your contribution :)

Answer (score 0):

Use column filters (or other ways) to show only the library content you need. Then create a view for the library and set it as standard, default view checking the box just underneath the view name field. Repeat this for all pages.

If you place the library as webpart to the page and it still shows another view, then click edit page > next, edit webpart and edit the current view.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I did this but by setting it as standard..... it effects all other webpart libraries on the same page on startup..... I.e if two webparts are on the same page both show the same content.....I want them to show different content based on the filter view I have pre-assigned